# extjs buildquery override does not work

Tags: extjs

I created a gridfilter like this:

```
var filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({filters: [
{type: 'string',  dataIndex: 'ContactName'}
]});
```

I wish to override the buildquery method to provide custom logic.

When I do:

```
filters.buildQuery = function(filters){
alert(Ext.util.JSON.encode(this.store.baseParams.filterParams));

};
```

It works fine. But when I move the alert inside another function like this:

```
buildQuery1 : function(filters){
alert(Ext.util.JSON.encode(this.store.baseParams));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
filters.buildQuery = function(filters){
buildQuery1(filters);
};
```

The alert does not show. And I get `this.store.baseParams is null or not an object.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
filters.buildQuery = function(filters)
{ 
buildQuery1(this,filters);
 };
```

AND:

```
buildQuery1 : function(scope,filters){ alert(Ext.util.JSON.encode(scope.store.baseParams)); }
```

Not sure why this works :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see all your code, however I got the impression that you are losing scope and mixing this with filters. To make sure what is in this call `console.dir (this)` and `console.dir (filters)` and see what object you have available